# How to format a date when looping a dynamic object in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am looping a data response from API and displaying in Angular. In this data, i have few fields with date format. Is it possible to check the object and format if its date to 'd-MMM-yyyy' format?

```
<table class="view-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of rowSource | keyvalue: keepOrder" class="view-table-th">
                <th class="view-table-th">
                  {{item.key}}
                </th>
                <td class="view-table-td">
                  {{item.value | date:'MMM'}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Payload

```
{
  "Employee ID": 1506,
  "First Name": "Sean",
  "Last Name": "Less",
  "Phone": "9234567896",
  "Email": "Sean@yahoo.com",
  "Hired Date": "2021-06-07T00:00:00", <-- Wanted to format this
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me which format do you want ?

Comment: 'd-MMM-yyyy'  format Manish

Answer (score 0):

Use the date pipe as needed :

```html
{{item.value | date:'d-MMM-yyyy'}}
```

All notations can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: I am getting the error - No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(value: string | number | Date, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a moment pipe.

first, you need to install the moment library then create a pipe.

***momentpipe.ts***

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'dateFormat' })
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Date | moment.Moment, dateFormat: string): any {
        return moment(value).format(dateFormat);
    }
}
```

**You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MomentPipe } from './momentPipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Your Modules
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...........,
    MomentPipe
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Use it in your View/Html like below.,**

```
{{ item.value | dateFormat: ''d-MMM-yyyy''}}
```

If you want to check that given data is date or not then you can craete one function in TS file.

**TS**

```
isValidDate(val): boolean { return moment(val).isValid();  } // true
```

And you can use in your HTML

**HTML**

```
<td class="view-table-td" *ngIf=isValidDate(item.value)>
    {{item.value | dateFormat: ''d-MMM-yyyy''}}
</td>
```